# Can't Locate Object Method - perl script

Tags: perl

Pretty new to Perl so there may be a very obvious solution here. I'm going through a logfile and basically adding certain things into a hash but I keep getting a:

"Can't locate object method "1339384721" via package "serv.int" (perhaps you forgot to load "serv.int"?) at logTest.pl line 37,  line 9."
I've initialized these variables and everything so I don't see why perl is complaining...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

my $LOGFILE = '/Users/user/Desktop/logTest';
my $downTime = 0;
my $serviceName = 0;
my %downTimeHash = ();

open(LOGFILE, $LOGFILE) or die ("Couldn't open the file.");

foreach my $line (<LOGFILE>) {
chomp($line);


#Checks for 'STATE' lines down
if ($line=~/\s*;DOWN*/ && ($line=~/STATE:\s+([^;]+)/ || $line=~/ALERT:\s+([^;]+)/)) {
#Get time service went down
    if ($line=~/\[(\d*)\]*/) {
        $downTime = $1;
    }
#Get service that went down
    if ($line=~/STATE:\s+([^;]+)/ || $line=~/ALERT:\s+([^;]+)/) {
        $serviceName = $1;
    }   
#Add service and down time to hash
%downTimeHash = ($serviceName->$downTime);
}
}

print "%downTimeHash \n";
```

Comment: The '1339384721' and 'serv.int' are the two variables I'm adding into the hash.

Comment: Did you mean to use `$serviceName => $downTime` instead of `$serviceName -> $downTime` ?

Comment: apparently so :) that fixed it! haha

Comment: This question explains the problem, quotes the exact error message, shows the relevant source code, isn't overly long, follows basic kwalitee guidelines, is reasonably well formatted, has a reasonable subject. That already makes it a vastly better question than a dozen others I've seen today: +1 from me. - I wouldn't vote to close as "too localised" just because the mistake was a simple typo. That reason for closing is wrong as the mistake is easy to make, and will reoccur with other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have used `=>` rather than `->`.